# Problem with writing to a file message.content with emojis Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

This is the error I get when I try to write down the message.content of a post containing emojis. How I can avoid that?

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f609' in position 
81: character maps to

Thank you in advance.

This is the code i'm using:

```
async def posts(ctx):
    f = open("file.txt", "w")
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        f.write(message.content + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible to show some code?

Comment: Done, sorry I forgot to add the code

Comment: Next time add the code in your question. Using the edit button. Instead of creating a new answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you dont use utf-8 encoding. The standard encoding that the open() function uses doesnt support emoji's. Thus the error.

To counter this problem you need to add `encoding="utf-8"` to your code:

```
async def posts(ctx):
    f = open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        f.write(message.content + "\n")

    f.close()
```